# How to convert contact form 7 submission to post after submission?

Tags: posts, forms

I have developed Contact Form 7 and I want to create a post directly after the user submits the form in WordPress. I am not able to do that.

Can anyone suggest any plugin or method?

Comment: search for the calls at "do_action" in the plugin code to know which hooks are available

Comment: In which plugin. @mmm.

Comment: in  contact form 7

Comment: What is the use of that.

Comment: not able to understand.Please explain in brief.Your help will be appreciated.

Comment: What Happened @mmm